# Cannot import csv or txt file into Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I just started learning Postgresql, and cannot figure out how to import a csv or text file into it. I do not have sql background, and I am not sure if I need to create a table in the database with exactly the same column names as the csv file I want to import. I cannot open my csv file because it is too big (10G), so I do not know what its column names are. In this case, how can I import it to Postgresql. Another thing is that I am not sure if I need to put the csv file in the certain document.

Comment: To peek at the first few lines of the file, use the `head` UNIX command. You must create the table first, then you can import data with the `COPY` command.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, do you mean the created table must have exactly the same column names as the csv file?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you don't specify columns with the `COPY` command, the columns will be matched first to first and so on. You can reorder columns by specifying them in the `COPY` command. The *names* of the columns are irrelevant unless you use the `HEADER` option, then they are read from the file.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried again, but the error code tells me it cannot open my CSV file Permission denied, I am using my university's internet, is that the problem?

Comment: If the file is on the client side, you need `COPY FROM STDIN` - best used with `\copy` from the `psql` client.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am not sure how to use it. Does postgresql have a command similar to the choose.files function in R that pops up a window allowing me to choose file?

Comment: There is no popping in PostgreSQL. Use `psql` to connect to the database from the command line and use `\copy` to load the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

To import a csv file into PostreSQL you will need to create the table that will match the columns of the csv file values in the necessary database.

When doing the import from Linux you will need to give the PostgreSQL user access to the csv file that is going to be imported.

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /path/to/csvfile
```

If you still don't have enough permissions then you can give full access to the file

```
sudo chmod 777 /path/to/csvfile
```

Then if you like you can execute from the Linux command line

```
/path/to/psql -d databasename -U postgres -c "copy tablename from '/path/to/csvfile' delimiter ',' csv"
```

If you want to execute it from the psql command line then you'd use

```
copy tablename from '/path/to/csvfile' delimiter ',' csv
```